# Powershell script is not showing each output or merging multiple servers csv's

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

The issue I am having; The script does not pull each individual servers csv and compile it into one csv. It brings in one particular server's information and if I change it to write-host it will bring back multiple reports of the same one.

What I am attempting to do is to reach out to all the servers in an OU, pull the specified csv, combine each csv into one. Each server should be on its own line. Can someone PLEASE help point me in the right direction?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# Select the servers you want to hit $servers = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU" -filter *).name

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $sourcefolder = 'C$\folder\'
    $sourcefiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcefolder -Filter serverinfo.csv
    $result = @()
    foreach ($file in $sourcefiles) {
        $data = Import-Csv $file.FullName
        $result += $data
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv '\\mycomputer\C$\folder\merged.csv' -NoTypeInformation
$result
```

Comment: You're resetting the result array inside your loop that's where the information from the previous iteration is lost basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting the `$result` array inside your loop that's where the information from the previous iteration is lost basically. A much easier approach can be leveraging the pipeline, then no array is needed:

```
$sourcefolder = 'C$\folder'
$servers | ForEach-Object{
    # makes a new UNC path using the server
    $target = [System.IO.Path]::Combine(
        "\\$_",
        $sourcefolder,
        'serverinfo.csv')

    # assuming there is a "serverinfo.csv" in "\\servername\C$\folder\serverinfo.csv"
    $item = Get-Item -Path $target -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # if the Csv could be found in that target
    if ($item) {
        # read it
        $item.FullName | Import-Csv
    }
} | Export-Csv 'path\to\merged.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `$item.FullName | Import-Csv`

Comment: @Theo good call, wasn't aware for UNC path that was required

Comment: So, how do I select an answer? The $item.fullname | import-csv combined with the above answer is the fix I needed, you guys kick butt!

Comment: @BobSnarley glad it worked and thanks to Theo for the hint on required `.FullName`. you can click the [checkmark to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/962245)

Comment: Any chance I could convince you Santiago to help me format the cells to autosize? It would be fantastic! You guys are a job saver... thank you so much!

Comment: @BobSnarley Csv is a plain text format, there is no way to tell Excel you want to autosize. What you can do is use `Export-Excel`: `... | Export-Excel 'path\to\merged.xlsx' -AutoSize -AutoFilter` but this would require you to install it (because its not builtin to powershell, see https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: Well crap, there is so much more stuff that I really need help with. But, I suppose I can post another question. I have another script that is having issues pulling all the information I needed. Compounding my issue is... I have to figure out how to import all this into excel 365

Comment: @BobSnarley thats correct, you can ask a new question focusing on that specific issue but I'm sure as long as the question has all necessary information someone will be able to help you. thats all what this site is about ;)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon any chance you could take a look at that other one? I would really appreciate the assistance!